# Indefinite integral of $\frac{3+x}{3-x}$

Tags: integration

I have tried to split the integral into a sum -> integral of $\frac{3}{3-x}$ and integral of $\frac{x}{3-x}$. Please let me know if it is the right way to deal with this kind of integrals.

Comment: Nope, that's wrong. Try $y=3-x$ and see what happens :-)

Comment: Hint: $3+x=6-(3-x)$.

Comment: What you did is not mathematically incorrect but it is also not the most efficient way to compute the integral. When integrating an "improper fraction" (i.e. when the degree of the numerator is greater than or equal to the degree of the denominator), you should use polynomial division to "reduce" the fraction. Hopefully you will be left with something you know how to integrate.

Comment: The idea with rational functions is to split them into sums of rational functions where the denominator has a higher degree than the numerator. In your case, 

$$\frac{3+x}{3-x} = \frac{-(3-x) + 6}{3-x} = -1 + \frac{6}{3-x}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal is to make the power in the numerator strictly smaller than that in the denominator.

$$\int \frac{3 + x}{3 - x} dx = \int \left( -1 + \frac{6}{3 - x} \right) dx = -x - 6 \ln (3 - x) + C$$

Answer (score 2):

The idea with rational functions is to split them into sums of rational functions where the denominator has a higher degree than the numerator.

This can always be done, and can in general be proven using polynomial division. With polynomials, if $p$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ and $q$ is a polynomial of degree $m$, then there exist some polynomials $k$ and $r$ such that $p = k\cdot q + r$, where the degree of $k$ is $m-n$ and the degree of $r$ is **smaller** than $n$, i.e. $\deg(p)=\deg(q)+\deg(k)$ and $\deg(r)<\deg(q)$.

This means that, when we have a rational function $\frac pq$, we can **always** rewrite it as $$\frac pq = \frac{kq+r}{q} = \frac{kq}{q} + \frac rq = k+\frac rq$$ which means that integrating $\frac pq$ is equivalent to integrating a polynomial ($k$) which we know how to do, and integrating a rational function where the degree of the numerator is smaller than the degree of the denominator.

---

Note that you often don't need to resort to any strict algorithm for polynomial division (although, of course, [it exists and is not hard to do!)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_division) since one can do the division "on the fly". In particular, with degree one polynomials, you can always do the following:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{ax+b}{cx+d} &= \frac{\frac ac(cx+\frac{cb}{a})}{cx+d}\\
&=\frac ac\cdot \frac{cx+d-d+\frac{cb}{a}}{cx+d}\\
&=\frac ac\cdot \left(\frac{cx+d}{cx+d}+\frac{\frac{cb}{a} - d}{cx+d}\right)\\
&=\frac ac + \frac ac\cdot \frac{\frac{cb}{a} - d}{cx+d}
\end{align}$$

which, while looking complicated, is really just a series of very basic operations. In your case, they amount to

$$\frac{3+x}{3-x} = \frac{-(3-x) + 6}{3-x} = -1 + \frac{6}{3-x}.$$

$$\frac{3+x}{3-x} = \frac{-(3-x) + 6}{3-x} = -1 + \frac{6}{3-x}$$